# Link back to restatable

Tags: hyperref, memoir, ntheorem

I am using ntheorem with restatable and I would like to have a link back (hyperref) from the restated theorem to the original theorem (the restatable). MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\begin{restatable}{theorem}{th}
Blah
\end{restatable}

\chapter{Two}

%Should link back to restatable in Chapter One
%(without extra \ref, but directly within \th*)
\th*

\end{document}
```

Thank you for any hints, best regards

Answer (score 2):

The following could work. If you want to use another theoremstyle you will have to adapt it too:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools,xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd \thmt@restatable{\@xa\protected@edef\csname the#2\endcsname}
                           {\def\thmt@tmp@restatename{#3}\@xa\protected@edef\csname the#2\endcsname}{}{\fail}


\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ 
   \ifcsname thmt@tmp@restatename\endcsname 
   \ifthmt@thisistheone ##2\else\ref{thmt@@\thmt@tmp@restatename}\fi
   \else ##2\fi
   \theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ 
   \ifcsname thmt@tmp@restatename\endcsname
   \ifthmt@thisistheone ##2\else\ref{thmt@@\thmt@tmp@restatename}\fi
   \else ##2\fi
   \  (##3)\theorem@separator]%
  }
\makeatother
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\begin{theorem}
some theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{th}
Blah
\end{restatable}

\chapter{Two}

%Should link back to restatable in Chapter One
%(without extra \ref, but directly within \th*)
\th*

\end{document}
```

If the word "Theorem" (or else) should be included within the link, the following theorem style can be used:

```
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[
   \ifcsname 
        thmt@tmp@restatename\endcsname 
        \ifthmt@thisistheone 
            \hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2
        \else
            \mbox{\hyperref[thmt@@\thmt@tmp@restatename]{\theorem@headerfont ##1~##2}} 
        \fi
   \else 
        \hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2
    \fi
   \theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[
   \ifcsname 
        thmt@tmp@restatename\endcsname
        \ifthmt@thisistheone 
            \hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2
        \else
            \mbox{\hyperref[thmt@@\thmt@tmp@restatename]{\theorem@headerfont ##1~##2}}
        \fi
   \else 
        \hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2
   \fi
   \  (##3)\theorem@separator]%
  }
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to include "Theorem" in the clickable hyperlink? I couldn't find the actual link part within your code, just the reference. But its a useful start anyway, Thank you!

Comment: @thewaywewalk sure, one only need do use \hyperref instead of \ref

Comment: Does it work for you? I tried various variations of e.g. `\hyperref[thmt@@\thmt@tmp@restatename]{Theorem \ref*{thmt@@\thmt@tmp@restatename} }`, and I always get a missing item error. And out of curiosity: where is the actual label hidden in your code?

Comment: @thewaywewalk put it in an \mbox: `\mbox{\hyperref[thmt@@\thmt@tmp@restatename]{##1~##2}}`

Comment: As from your comments it was not immediately clear how to make it work (the word theorem appeared two times), I edited your answer to complete it. Feel free to roll back if you don't agree or simplify/correct it if needed. Thank you! Unfortunately I can't accept your answer, but maybe @markus23 can?